# Set default value in form field

Tags: php, html, forms, joomla

I have a form in a Joomla component in which the user needs to select a country and then a city depending on the country selected. In my case I only need one country. How can I edit or replace the code below to set the country to a default value and remove it from the form?

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="submit-location"><?php echo JText::_('COM_BT_PROPERTY_LOCATION');?></label>
   <?php echo $this->form->getInput('country'); ?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $this->form->getInput('city'); ?>
</div>
```

Thank you for your time. Any suggestion is much appreciated!

Comment: it can't be done I guess:/